# Finding mode in an array and displaying it with brackets in the list

Tags: java

Hello I am trying to display the mode in the array with brackets like

32 31 [10] 32 [10] [10] [10] 12 [10] 34

as 10 is the most occurring number

I am able to find the mode and display the mode with brackets but when when there is no mode in the array list it declares the first value as the mode. [1] 3 4 5. I don't want it to show brackets if there is no mode. All help will be appreciated.

```
public static int mode(int[] array) {
  int mode = array[0];
  int maxCount = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int value = array[i];
    int count = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[j] == value) count++;
        if (count > maxCount) {
            mode = value;
            maxCount = count;
        }
    }
  }
  return mode;
}
```

Comment: What  do you mean by display ? just print it ?

Comment: System.out.println .Yes i have created random array this is the method

Comment: Making no sense to me. What do you mean by random array ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you know the mode, you can print the elements in a loop:

```
int[] array = ...
int mode = mode(array);
boolean first = true;
for (int elt : array) {
    // print separator unless it's the first element
    if (first) {
        first = false;
    } else {
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    if (elt == mode) {
        System.out.print(elt);
    } else {
        System.out.print('[');
        System.out.print(elt);
        System.out.print(']');
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Note that the above works only for arrays that have a unique mode. If the array is multimodal, the `mode()` method arbitrarily breaks ties in favor of the first value only. If you want to bracket all modal values, then `mode()` needs to be modified to return an array of values and the printing loop needs to test if each element is in the returned array (rather than the current test `if (elt == mode) ...`.

Comment: if there is no mode its displaying the first number as mode how can i get rid of that . example [2] 3 4

Comment: @maria - Rather than saying that the example has no mode, I think the correct terminology is that it is multimodal (see, e.g., the Wikipedia article ["Mode (statistics)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29))--all values are considered modes. So the question for you is: How do you want to break ties for multimodal data? My code arbitrarily breaks ties in favor of the first mode found.

Comment: correct its multimodal if i have more then one mode like [1] [1] [2] [2] 4.

Comment: @maria - Ah. So you want to print the array with all modes bracketed? So the example array in your first comment should print as `[2] [3] [4]`?

Comment: no sir i want that if my list is 1 2 3 4 and there is no mode as all numbers are occurring only one time. it don't put brackets on 1 (the first value in the list) . As it is doing it when there is no mode

Comment: @maria - I'm confused by your requirements. On the one hand you say that a multimodal array like `1 1 2 2 4` should print as `[1] [1] [2] [2] 4` but on the other hand you say that if the array is `1 2 3 4` (which has four values tied as the mode) you don't want any bracketing at all. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: @maria - Note that the Wikipedia article I linked to describes a distribution where all values occur equally frequently as an "extreme case" of a multimodal distribution, not as a distribution with no mode.

Comment: let me put in another way suppose all the numbers are different . As we know that mode is the value that appears most often in a set of data.  With my current code it shows the result  [4] 3 5 2.

Comment: @maria - There's a way to modify the code to print brackets around all modal values, if that would be useful to you. It would print `1 2 3 4` as `[1] [2] [3] [4]`. Should I bother editing my answer to show that? Alternatively, the `mode()` method can be modified to return -1 (or some other signal value) when there are ties (in which case `1 1 2 2 4` would print with no brackets).

Comment: No that wont be useful can you show me how can i make the code print multimodal [1] [1] [2] [2] 4

Comment: @maria - Not without also printing `[1] [2] [3] [4]` (or `[1] [1] [2] [2]`, etc.)

Comment: that would not satisfy the purpose of the program as I am trying to find the mode.

Comment: @maria - At the risk of repeating myself: For a uniform distribution, all values are modes. Do you simply want the special case that whenever every value is a mode you want none bracketed?

Comment: 1 and 2 are occurring twice 1 1 2 2 but other numbers are not .so the out should show [1] [2] 4 6 [2] 7 8 [1] 9 where 4 ,6, 7 ,8 9 are numbers which are not occurring frequently as the are occurring once as compared to 1 and 2 which are occurring twice

Comment: Sorry I think i have confused you.Its okey if you don't understand my requirement.

Comment: @maria - If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to suppress bracketing in the one special case that all numbers would receive brackets. You can do this by modifying `mode()` to return an array of all values tied for the mode and to return an empty array if the return value would otherwise have had a length equal to the number of unique values in the array. (There are lots of posts on the web about how to find the number of unique elements. See, e.g., [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/81781/number-of-distinct-elements-in-an-array))